# Unregister com library after uninstall

Tags: c#, com, wix

I have a library (addin for Solidworks) which implements ComRegisterFunction and inside RegisterFunction adds keys to registry. Also I'm using Wix toolset for creating installer. 
When user tries to uninstall my addin, there is a tiny time interval in the end of uninstallation process and when he presses *Cancel*, all files are restored but my library becomes unregistered.
As a solution I've tried to mark library file as "*Permanent*" and added custom action to unregister and remove it before *InstallFinalize*. But it did not help.

How can I deal with this problem? How my library can be registered again?

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="setRegCommand" Before="comReg" />
  <Custom Action="setUnregCommand" Before="comUnreg" />
  <Custom Action="comReg" Before="InstallFinalize"> (NOT REMOVE) </Custom>
  <Custom Action="comUnreg" After="RemoveFiles"> REMOVE~="ALL" </Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetDeleteActionPropertyValues" Before="DeleteAction" />
  <Custom Action="DeleteAction" Before="InstallFinalize">REMOVE~="ALL"</Custom>
  <Custom Action="netWarning" Before="LaunchConditions">WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_45_OR_LATER_INSTALLED = 0</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Fragment>
<CustomAction Id="SetDeleteActionPropertyValues" Property="DeleteAction" Value="INSTALLLOCATION=[INSTALLLOCATION];XXXINSTALLFOLDER=[XXXINSTALLFOLDER]" />
<CustomAction Id="DeleteAction" Return="check" Execute='commit' Impersonate='no' BinaryKey="CustomAction.CA.dll" DllEntry="DeleteFilesCA" />
<Binary Id='CustomAction.CA.dll' SourceFile='$(var.CustomAction.TargetDir)CustomAction.CA.dll'/>
</Fragment>
```

Custom Action

```
public static ActionResult DeleteFilesCA(Session session)
    {
        session.Log("Begin DeleteFilesCA");

        try
        {
            string installDir = session.CustomActionData["INSTALLLOCATION"];
            string xxxDir = session.CustomActionData["XXXINSTALLFOLDER"];
            if (Directory.Exists(installDir))
            {
                Directory.Delete(installDir, true);
                if(IsDirectoryEmpty(xxxDir))
                {
                    Directory.Delete(xxxDir);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }

    private static bool IsDirectoryEmpty(string path)
    {
        return !Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path).Any();
    }
```

Registration/unregistration of com library

```
<Property Id ='comReg'/>
<CustomAction Id="setRegCommand" Property="comReg" Value='"[WindowsFolder]\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "[INSTALLLOCATION]\plugin.dll" /codebase' />
<CustomAction Id="comReg" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec64"
            Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>

<Property Id='comUnreg'/>
<CustomAction Id="setUnregCommand" Property="comUnreg" Value='"[WindowsFolder]\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "[INSTALLLOCATION]\plugin.dll" /codebase /unregister' />
<CustomAction Id="comUnreg" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec64"
            Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no"/>
```

Comment: The right way to do it is to figure out what changes `ComRegisterFunction` makes to the registry, and configure them as normal WiX actions rather than using a custom action. Then they could be rolled back using normal mechanisms. If I recall correctly, WiX comes with a tool (don't remember the name) that can watch an installer run, note the changes it makes, and generate a WiX source describing those changes.

Comment: ComRegisterFunction contains additional logic to register addin for Solidworks. Moving this logic to normal WiX actions does nothing and Solidworks does not see the plugin. We must call RegAsm.exe to make it work. But in uninstall sequence comUnreg custom action isn't rolled back if uninstallation cancelled.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "normal WiX actions" but COM registry data can be extracted with heat.exe and added to the WiX source, and if this other logic is registry data then put it in registry items. Then it all just works. You've got this problem because you're doing it this way, and doing it the recommended way will fix it. Also the WiX RemoveFile element will create MSI entries to remove files and again that requires no code.